# jquery min width calculation (addition)

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to set a parent div tag min-width to the equivalent width of all the children inside.  Is there a way to do that?

For example,

```
<div id="Wrap">
 <div id="sidebar">
 </div>
 <div id="content">
 </div>
</div>

#sidebar{
width: 325px;
}

#content{
width: 500px;
}
```

Then the jquery will add the sidebar and the content div tag up and set the min-width.  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery's css() method you can read and set css properties:

```
var a = $('#sidebar').css('width').replace('px', ''); // get sidebar's width
var b = $('#content').css('width').replace('px', ''); // get content's width

var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
c = c + "px";
$('#Wrap').css('width', c);   // set Wrap's width to c value
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate all divs within `#Wrap` and set its width?

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/BbcmU/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $("#Wrap").children("div").each(function() {      
        total += $(this).width();  
    });
    $('#Wrap').css({ 'min-width': total });
});
```